# kernel system call inplace of "route" command to add host ip to routing table

Tags: linux, dns, routes, gateway

I need to traverse all data packets of ftp server host from ppp0 interface, So for that i am using below command which add ftp ip address to route entry with specific gateway.

```
route add -host ftpaddress.com gw 10.64.64.64 dev ppp0
```

It is working fine but i observe sometime command is taking too much time in execution. I think it is because of ftp server address resolution. I want to do same operation using kernel system calls. Can anyone give me direction or some of hits from which i can add, delete or get ftp ip in/from route entries with specific configuration.

Or if there are any other way to do so then please let me know.

Comment: If there is any way to insert, remove and get FTP ip address to route entry from kernel system call then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a problem with (reverse) DNS resolution, you can pass the option `-n` (numeric) to route. Then route will not issuing any DNS queries at all.

```
route add -n -host host_address gw 10.64.64.64 dev ppp0
```

Also you can put the hostname and IP into `/etc/hosts` on your box. Having default `/etc/nsswitch` confiugration, this file will get considered before any DNS query gets issued:

*/etc/hosts*

```
10.64.64.64 vpn.gateway.local #or whatever hostname
```

Comment: So i need to write ip of host and host address in /etc/hosts file or i need to write ip of gateway and host address in /etc/hosts file? I think it is ip of host right?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/hosts` on your computer, not on the gateway

Comment: We are having dynamic configuration for host address so we can't fix host address and host ip in /etc/hosts file. We need to find ip at run time and need to add it in to this /etc/hosts file from application right?

Comment: If you have control over the infrastructure, just make reverse dns working properly

Comment: Oh missed to mention the `-n` option. This should help you. Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried this option. It seems that working to me but today again i observe same issue again with these option where it is taking 2 to 3 minutes to coming out of route command's execution.

Comment: Can you capture and analyze the network traffic with wireshark?

Comment: No, It is actually embedded system which doesn't have this tools if you tell are telling me on FTP server side then i can.

Comment: You can sniff on the switch or use `arpsoof` to redirect traffic over your PC. It looks like you'll need to do that if you want to solve the problem